# netstat suspicious ssh sockets

Tags: sockets, ssh, netstat, rootkit

When i run netstat -t on my server, I get the following among others:

-sshd    14369        root    3u  IPv4 1317773      0t0  TCP localhost:ssh->82.77.64.139:62334 (ESTABLISHED)
-sshd    14494        root    3u  IPv4 1319053      0t0  TCP localhost:ssh->218.87.109.151:22536 (ESTABLISHED)
-sshd    14495        sshd    3u  IPv4 1319053      0t0  TCP localhost:ssh->218.87.109.151:22536 (ESTABLISHED)

When typing w no one appears, but me from 82.77.64.139.

Is this a rootkit?

Comment: Try with `netstat -nlpt` to also list the processes.  Then you can also run `netstat -ltpe` to see the associated users.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so it seems that if you telnet to the specified port, and run netstat, the connection is ESTABLISHED. Didn't knew that.
Probably someone scanned the ports, no backdoor present thankfully :)